# If $db_prefix is "assumed to be a string", then does Drupal automatically sort what is a sharable table in the DB?

Tags: 6, migrations, multi-sites

```
$db_prefix = 'drupal_';
```

I've found many examples of installations which pick through the tables and place these in an array. And then there is the example of the site I am migrating where it only contained the above string. So, does Drupal *sort it all out* in the case of this simple string?

What is the big idea I feel I am missing about multi-sites? 
(haha the mysteries of the D framework!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$db_prefix can either be a string or an array, have a look at the documentation: [Share a single database across multiple sites](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/function/db_prefix_tables/6), the [db_prefix_tables](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/function/db_prefix_tables/6) function take care of this job.

Comment: Is this function automatically applied from the settings.php file during the boot strap phase? Then the choice of using an array or string is limited or use all of the tables (even though some of the tables are apparently not shareable)?

Comment: $db_prefix is a [global](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/globals/6) and is defined in setting, but the function applies it on every db_query call.